# Jetty 8 vs Jetty 9 for production environment

Tags: jetty, jetty-8

We are currently using Jetty 8 for a production environment serving low latency traffic. We were wondering what would be the advantages to move to jetty 9, given that we have a very low latency requirement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jetty 9 has a refactored IO layer over Jetty 8 which should garner you improvements in that area.  See this blog for information on how and why Jetty is a best of breed in this area.

https://webtide.com/jetty-in-techempower-benchmarks/

Specifically look down for the latency tests where Jetty easily came out on top.

[edit] I should note that this is perhaps not an appropriate question for this forum since it is outside of the intent of stack overflow and more inline with server fault...just fair warning.

Comment: not sure why the month got tweaked there, but I updated to a valid link

Comment: At this point Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 are both EOL so just use Jetty 9.